# How can I retrieve many entities by composite key?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, composite-key

I am using Entity Framework (4.2 if that matters) and I have a model which has a composite primary key(two int columns).  I have a list of pairs of ints which represent a list of objects I'd like to pull out of the database.  Is there an easy way to pull all of these objects using a single query?

I have tried joining the query with my list like this:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = GetIds();

var data =
    from e in ctx.CompositeEntities
    join i in ids on new {e.KeyA, e.KeyB} equals new {KeyA = i.Item1, KeyB = i.Item2}
    select e;
```

However this always causes an exception "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple`2'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to see a cleaner way to do this, but... at least it should work.

**Solution1**

What you need : concatenate your tuple list, then concatenante the "int keys" from your entity, using [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx). As it takes only double or decimal as parameters, you've got to cast your int in double first.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = GetIds();

var concatenatedIds = ids.Select(m => m.Item1 + "," + m.Item2).ToList();

var result = ctx.CompositeEntities
                .Where(conatenatedIds.Contains(
                       SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.KeyA) + 
                       "," + 
                       SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.KeyB)));
```

**Solution2**

Use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = GetIds();

var predicate = Predicate.False<CompositeEntity>();
foreach (var tuple in ids) 
   predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.KeyA == tuple.Item1 && m.KeyB == tuple.Item2);

var result = ctx.CompositeEntities.Where(predicate);
```

**Solution3**

Enumerate first, then do comparison.
Of course, this will take all CompositeEntities from database.

Comment: I can't find Predicate.False<>() and predicate.Or() - what should I reference to get these?

Comment: @Rattle see the link to PredicateBuilder, everything is explained on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to try this, but try using something like this where clause.

```
from e in ctx.CompositeEntities
where ids.Where(i => e.KeyA == i.Item1  && e.KeyB == i.Item2).Count() > 0
select e;
```

===== EDIT =====

well it fails with the same exception, thank you for the encouragement.

What about the following, assuming you key is int and not bigint

```
public class e1 {
    public int KeyA { get; set; }
    public int KeyB { get; set; }
}

public class e1Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<e1> {
    public e1Configuration()
        : base() {
            HasKey(x => new { x.KeyA, x.KeyB });
    }
}

public class TestEFContext : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<e1> es { get; set; }

    public TestEFContext(String cs)
        : base(cs) {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new e1Configuration());            
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(String[] args) {


        using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(@"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True")) {
            c.es.Add(new e1 { KeyA = 1, KeyB = 1 });
            c.es.Add(new e1 { KeyA = 1, KeyB = 2 });
            c.es.Add(new e1 { KeyA = Int32.MaxValue, KeyB = 2 });
            c.SaveChanges();
        }

        List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = new List<Tuple<int, int>> { 
            new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1), 
            new Tuple<int, int>(Int32.MaxValue, 2),};

        List<Int64> lis = (from t in ids select (Int64)t.Item1 * 2^ 32 + t.Item2).ToList();

        using (TestEFContext c0 = new TestEFContext(@"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True")) {
            var v = from e in c0.es
                    where lis.Contains((Int64)e.KeyA * 2 ^ 32 + e.KeyB)
            select e;

            Console.WriteLine(v.Count());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with an almost identical scenario, but I'll try and map it to the one above - so let me know if it doesn't compile.

This is the same basic idea Raphaël's example 2, but I couldn't get that to run. I'm building up the Predicate as a union of queries for individual entities, one for each tuple.

```
  List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = GetIds();

  ids.Aggregate<Tuple<int,int>,IQueryable<CompositeEntity>>(
      null,
      (current, id) => 
        current == null ? SingleCompositeEntity(ctx.CompositeEntities, id)
        : current.Union(SingleCompositeEntity(ctx.CompositeEntities, id)));
}


private static IQueryable<CompositeEntity> 
        SingleCompositeEntity(IQueryable source, Tuple<int,int> tuple)
{
   return source.Where(m => m.KeyA == tuple.Item1 && m.KeyB == tuple.Item2)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but I think will work.

Add a property to your Entity Object to expose the keys as a Tuple.

```
public Tuple<int, int> TupleKey
{
    get { return new Tuple<int, int>(_keyA, _keyB);}
}
```

Then alter your query to use this new property.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = GetIds();

var data = from e in ctx.CompositeEntities
            where ids.Contains(e.TupleKey)
            select e;
```

Comment: I get the same exception, Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple`2'.

Comment: Unmapped properties (and a property without a setter can't be mapped in db) can't be use in a linq to entity query.